# MVC Razor syntax error when using Linq Any()

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, razor

I have a strange issue since upgrading to the latest version of VS2017; in any of my MVC Views where I use `.Any()` on a list in my ViewModel it shows an error:

`The type 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.`

However, it doesn't seem to cause any issues when running the application and it all works fine, I'm just confused about why this error shows.

Here's a snippet of code where I experience the issue, the error is highlighted under the `Model.BreakInLearnings.Any()` line:

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.StatusChangeReason, "Comment")
    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.StatusChangeReason, new { @rows = "4", @style = "resize: none", @class = "form-control" })
    @if (Model.BreakInLearnings.Any())
    {
        <label>Test BILs: @(Model.BreakInLearnings.Count) total.</label>
    }
</div>
```

Comment: Just delete the `bin` and `obj` folder from the project then reopen the solution and build. Problem should go away now.

Comment: Which versions of .net and mvc?